# Dual camera capturing photos with unexpected scale and offset on iPhone 14 Pro

Tags: ios, swift, avcapturephotooutput

I have a setup in which I capture both photos from the actual devices of the virtual `.builtinDualCamera`. I set the videoZoomFactor of the virtual device to the first of `virtualDeviceSwitchOverVideoZoomFactors`. Taking a photo results in two AVCapturePhotos. One from the wide angle camera and one from the telephoto camera. Since the photo from the wide angle camera is zoomed in, a part of the photo black (this is to be expected).

On an iPhone X, the photo from the wide angle camera has a scale of 1 divided by that videoZoomFactor (1.8), which is what I would expect.

On an iPhone 14 Pro, however, the scale seems to be different from the expected 1.0 / 3.0! The scale is often smaller, but in these examples it is even bigger. The image is also not completely centered!

[image: wide angle camera image]

[image: telephoto camera image]

**Why is this? And is there a way to calculate this scale and offset?**

My setup (simplified):

```
import AVFoundation

class DualCamera {
    
    enum DualCameraError: Error {
        case initialisation
    }
    
    private let device: AVCaptureDevice
    private let deviceInput: AVCaptureDeviceInput
    private let session = AVCaptureSession()
    private let photoOutput = AVCapturePhotoOutput()
    private let queue = DispatchQueue(label: "camera queue")
    private let cameraDelegate = DualCameraDelegate()
    
    init() throws {
        guard
            let device = AVCaptureDevice.DiscoverySession(
                deviceTypes: [.builtInDualCamera],
                mediaType: .video,
                position: .back)
                .devices
                .first,
            let deviceInput = try? AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: device)
        else {
            throw DualCameraError.initialisation
        }
        
        self.device = device
        self.deviceInput = deviceInput
        
        session.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSession.Preset.photo
        session.addInput(deviceInput)
        session.addOutput(photoOutput)
        
        photoOutput.isVirtualDeviceConstituentPhotoDeliveryEnabled = true
        
        deviceConfiguration { device in
            if let zoomFactor = device.virtualDeviceSwitchOverVideoZoomFactors.first {
                device.videoZoomFactor = CGFloat(zoomFactor.floatValue)
            }
        }
    }
    
    func deviceConfiguration(_ configuration: @escaping (AVCaptureDevice)->()) {
        queue.async { [self] in
            session.beginConfiguration()
            do {
                try device.lockForConfiguration()
                
                configuration(device)
                
                device.unlockForConfiguration()
            } catch(let error) {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }
            session.commitConfiguration()
        }
    }
    
    func shoot() {
        queue.async { [self] in
            let photoSettings = AVCapturePhotoSettings()
            photoSettings.virtualDeviceConstituentPhotoDeliveryEnabledDevices = device.constituentDevices

            photoOutput.capturePhoto(with: photoSettings, delegate: cameraDelegate)
        }
    }
}

class DualCameraDelegate: NSObject, AVCapturePhotoCaptureDelegate {

    func photoOutput(_ output: AVCapturePhotoOutput, didFinishProcessingPhoto photo: AVCapturePhoto, error: Error?) {
        
        // Do something with the photo
        print(photo)
    }
}
```

**Note:**
I expect `AVCameraCalibrationData` to be of help, but I cannot figure out how to use it with the limited documentation available.